# How to call a PHTML file within a CMS page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, static-block, magento2-dev-beta

**Magento 2**

I have installed a sample Bannerslider module downloaded from Magestore.

When I call `bannerslider.phtml` into CMS Home Page, it's showing unreliable error on the home page.

```
{{block class="Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow" template="bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

The error message is `We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.`

I changed the block class as well, still, it shows the same error.
Can you please suggest me a proper way?

If you need furthermore code detail, Please mentioned me in a comment. I am really stuck here.

After uncomment `SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer` in `.htaccess` file error message being the change and showing

```
Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow
```

By the way, the admin section of this module is working fine.

Block class

```
namespace Magento\Bannerslider\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Slideshow extends Template
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Bannerslider\Model\BannerFactory $bannerFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\Framework\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        $this->_fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->_bannerFactory = $bannerFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getBaseJs($fileName){

        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ).'bannerslider/js/'.$fileName;
    }
    public function getBannerData(){
        $banners = $this->_bannerFactory->create()
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
        foreach ($banners as $banner){
                $result['banners'][] = $banner->getData();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function getBannerImage($imageName) {

        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            );
        return $mediaDirectory.'bannerslider/images'.$imageName;
    }
}
```

Module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Bannerslider" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Comment: you need to uncoment SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer from .htaccess file to eloborate error.

Comment: Thank you Taral. I have done it. Now error message has been change. I have edited my question now.

Comment: Please show me your block class and module.xml code.

Comment: I had added block class and module.xml code to post.

Comment: @TaralPatoliya Thank you for your suggestion... It really helped for me!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try below code in cms page, If you want to call phtml with in cms page.

```
{{block class="Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow" template="Magento_Bannerslider::bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 24):

In magento,if you want to add block class in cms page, then you can tre below code

```
{{block class="Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow" template="Magento_Bannerslider::bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

**Formula is :**

```
{{block class="[BlockClassFullName]" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YourTemplateFileLocation].phtml"}}
```

**Default block:**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YourTemplateFileLocation].phtml"}}
```

***This is equal to Magento 1.X version code***

```
{{ block type="core/template" template="YourtemplateFileLocation.phtml"}}
```

Comment: hi @Amit, can we use cacheable="false" here? when used in cms

Comment: Can use but it makes you make non Cacheable

Comment: Yes i need that one, what is the syntax in using cms, i used it but it didn't work