# Dispaly Featured Catagory

Tags: magento2

Need Help for Magento 2, 
I have cretaed a attribute for category.
I want to display featured catagory list on home page using attribute,please help me for get collection of featured category.

Answer (score 2):

First You nedd to create a `phtml` file in your theme

> project/app/design/frontend/Magento/activerobots/Magento_Theme/templates/fetured-category.phtml

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryCollection->create();
$categories = $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSelect('featured_category')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $categoryCollection));      
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
    echo $category->getUrl();
}
```

Your attribute is `featured_category` u define in attribute filter.
Please Call this file in your homepage first.

**Use of Object manager is not correct method**

Comment: {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="featured_category" template="Tagsafari_default::featured_category.phtml"}} IS this currect?

Comment: {block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="featured_category" template="Tagsafari_Default::featured_category.phtml"}}

Comment: Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Tagsafari_Default::featured_category.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0' getting this error

Comment: Please Try This 
{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="featured_category" template="Tagsafari_Default::Tagsafari_Default::featured-category.phtml"}}

Comment: this time also getting same error

Comment: Please can u sure how to call phtml in cms page ..,Please follow this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85593/how-to-call-a-phtml-file-within-a-cms-page-magento-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95332/discussion-between-hardik-radadiya-and-magento-bhurio).